# RadioButton style property Padding not being applied

Tags: wpf, xaml, radio-button, padding, wpf-style

[Using .NET Framework 4.5.1]

I have the following resource set in one of my WPF Windows:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}" x:Key="baseStyle">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}" x:Key="basePlusEnabled" BasedOn="{StaticResource baseStyle}">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding TestIsRunning, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="RadioButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource basePlusEnabled}">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,-5,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding TestIsRunning, 
            Converter={StaticResource testIsRunningForegroundConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

However, the `Padding` style is not being applied to the `RadioButton`s in the window. (The other properties in the style are getting applied.)  If I explicitly specify the `Padding` in each `RadioButton`, then it works. What am I missing here?

EDIT:
Sample `RadioButton` instance:

```
<RadioButton Grid.Column="4" Content="Iowa" GroupName="Facility"
    IsChecked="{Binding IowaFacilityChecked1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
    Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

change `TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}"` to `TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}"`

Comment: Can't, as I have other UI elements using those styles.

Comment: can you please share the UI structure?. How radiobutton is declared and where?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for - what do you mean by the "UI structure"? One does not "declare" a ``RadioButton``.

Comment: portion of xaml structure where radiobutton is declared.

Comment: sample ``RadioButton`` added to OP

Comment: Bro, I think radio button not supporting Padding. I have prepared same structure and find out that it is working for button. But not able to see any padding effect for radio button at resource level styles.

Comment: ``RadioButton`` _does_ support ``Padding``. It works if I explicitly include it in the specific RB instance.

Comment: -1. Changing `TargetType` doesn't work, the `Padding` is still ignored. It is applied only when you set the property directly on the `RadioButton`, as @Conrad said.